# Java: ArrayList объявлен как глобальный для класса, но в методе получается пустым

Tags: java, arraylist

Подскажите пожалуйста, получаю в итоге в методе max пустой список

```
public class Main {
    public static ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    public static int max() {
        for (Integer number : numbers) {
                if (number > max) {
                    max = number;
                }
        }
    }

    static public void main(String[] args) {
        while(scan.hasNextInt()) {
            int number = scan.nextInt();

            // stop reading
            if (number == 0) {
                break;
            }

            numbers.add(number);
        }

        // Get a result of your code

        System.out.println(max());
    }
```

Comment: этот код не компилируется

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых код не компилируется, так как в методе `max` не определена и не возвращается переменная `max`, а также в методе `main` не определена переменная `Scanner scan`.

Но даже если исправить код, то список вполне может оставаться пустым, так как если сканер не найдёт целое число и его `hasNextInt()` вернёт false, соответственно никакое число не будет добавлено в список.

Рабочий код:

```java
public static ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();

public static Integer max() {
    Integer max = null;
    for (Integer number : numbers) {
        if (max == null || number > max) {
            max = number;
        }
    }
    return max;
}

static public void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    while (scan.hasNextInt()) {
        int number = scan.nextInt();

        // stop reading
        if (number == 0) {
            break;
        }

        numbers.add(number);
    }

    // Get a result of your code

    System.out.println("MAX: " + numbers + ": " + max());
}
```

Примеры работы:

```
dw
MAX: []: null
```

```
4 18 25 19
0
MAX: [4, 18, 25, 19]: 25
```

```
123 abcd 987 xyzMAX: [123]: 123
```